# I have blocked the URL for a user who is not logged in, but after the user logs in he still cannot access the URL

Tags: java, spring-boot

Title says it all.

- `WebSecurityConfig`

  ```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/users/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(h2ConsolePath + "/**").permitAll().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/api/auth/loginAndRegisterForm")
            .successForwardUrl("/api/users/tripAdvisorHomePage").and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/api/auth/loginAndRegisterForm")
            .permitAll();
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
  ```

As you can see I have `.antMatchers("/api/users/**").authenticated()` and that works, I cant access that URL, getting `Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource` with code `401`.

But when I go back and enter a credentials and get redirected to `successForwardUrl("/api/users/tripAdvisorHomePage")` its still `Full authentication is required`.

- This is my `login` method:

  ```
  @PostMapping("/login")
  @Transactional
  public ResponseEntity<?> login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("login") 
  LoginRequest loginRequest, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.
            authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtHelper.generateJwtCookie(user);
    System.out.println(jwtCookie);


    model.addAttribute("login", loginRequest);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString());
    headers.add("Location", "/api/users/tripAdvisorHomePage");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
  ```
- This is my method to show page if user is logged in.

  ```
  @GetMapping("/tripAdvisorHomePage")
  public String index() {
    return "tripAdvisorHomePage";
  }
  ```

And on top of class I have `@RequestMapping("/api/users")` so the URL for that `index` API is like in `WebSecurityConfig` - `"/api/users/tripAdvisorHomePage"`

I tried to find something useful around but there are all specific ways for each and other and so far I had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken here, but the following looks odd:

```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString()); // What now?
  headers.add("Location", "/api/users/tripAdvisorHomePage");
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

The `Set-Cookie` header is never part of the *actually returned* `ResponseEntity`. Try adding the `Set-Cookie` and `Location` header to the same response entity:

```
return ResponseEntity
  .status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
  .location("/api/users/tripAdvisorHomePage")
  .header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
  .build();
```

(untested)

Comment: Yeah, thats it. I followed some tutorial and the guy didnt create any HTML just used postman for testing, so I had some troubles while returning HTML page, that was the reason why my `ResponseEntity` and `Set-Cookie` looked like that. I assumed as I wrote that something is not good because I didint return cookie in response entity, but nvm I'm learning. Your answer is good and so far its work. I just added `URI.create` before URL by suggestion from IDE and all is fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, fair point :) I didn't notice the `URI` type on `.location`.